# android drawerlayout with actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to use `DrawerLayout` and `Actionbarsherlock` but after I add `actionbarsherlock` library I'm getting an error.

In one case in eclipse layout preview window I'm getting the error:

```
The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
```

If I add android.support.v4 jar as external jar im getting the error runtime

```
error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
```

How can I use `Drawerlayout` with `actionbarsherlock` library ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [this](https://github.com/tobykurien/SherlockNavigationDrawer) and [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-actionbarsherlock-side-menu-navigation-drawer-in-android/) example. Your problem might be caused by the fact that you didn't add a correct Android Support Library -> v4 r13 (currently there is a revison 18 and you should include the newest one).

Comment: problem was that there was old support library in actionbarsherlock